# Unable to click on javascript element through selenium driver

Tags: selenium, javascript

I am using given below xpath but my script is not clicking on these element
`Login_Btn = "(//a[contains(text(),'Login')])[2]";`

OR

`"//div[@id='bd_login']/a" ;`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(Login_Btn)).click();
```

**FED code :**

```
<div class="row emailExist">
<div class="rowL">
<div class="rowR">
<div class="cover">
<i id="bd_email_err" class="erLbl"/>
<div id="bd_login" class="dspN" style="margin-top:5px">
An account already exists for this email. Please use a different email or 
<a ").click();"="" #login_layer="" onclick="$(" href="javascript:;">Login</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share html so we can help

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Login_Btn));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: you should add description for your answer, so that user can understand the meaning of code.